# TortoiseHG Revision Graph

Tags: tortoisehg

I would like to know what the little star means in the TortoiseHG revision graph? I had a look around the docs and could not find a key for it.

Comment: Im guessing but it might show recent revisions, the stars disappear after closing and re-opening Repo-Explorer and re-appear after pulling or commiting new revisions.

Comment: No need to close and reopen Repo-Explorer, just press the **Reset Marks** button (also available in the View menu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's in the docs, but you already answered your question in your comment:

When you pull or commit and then refresh the Repository Explorer, the new revision(s) are marked with green text and this little star, so you can recognize the new revision(s) immediately.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation says http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/changelog.html

> Changesets which are added to the
>   repository after the changelog tool
>   was opened are marked with *green* stars
>   in the graph. This includes recent
>   commits, pulled changesets, and
>   applied patches.

Thats correct but my stars are yellow, too.

Comment: mine are yellow too. But with text in green.